# PagerSetting Modes in ASP.NET GridView Control - First Prev 1 2 3 Next Last

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In GridView Control I want pagination like- First Prev 1 2 3 4 Next Last. In my below code I'm able to do First Prev Next Last but not sure how to show number between Prev Next. Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `PagerSettings` tag to your gridview, something like:

```
<PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="4"  FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last"/>
```

or possibly a `PagerTemplate` for more control over the output.

[PagerSettings - MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagersettings?view=netframework-4.8.1)

[PagerTemplate - MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagertemplate?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-web-ui-webcontrols-gridview-pagertemplate)

Comment: Hi David, I tried above code but its throwing error. "Content ('<PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="4"  FirstPageText="First"LastPageText="Last"/>') does not match any properties within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView', make sure it is well-formed". Also the link which you provided there is no example like -  First Prev 1 2 3 4 Next Last. Could you please help. Please see below code which i m using - <PagerSettings Mode= "NextPreviousFirstLast" PageButtonCount="4" PreviousPageText="Previous" NextPageText="Next" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" />

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a PagerSettings tag to your gridview, something like this:

Then alignment comes into web page like this:
**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SODU.png)**

On row created event instead of **...** just rename the button as **Prev** and Next 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFB34.png)